# Inserting HTML tags inside a PHP variable

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".'<strong>'.clean_string($cname).'</strong>'."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
```

This form is then send my email, I wanted the first line of the email to be:

First Name: **Entered name**

but what I get is:

First Name: `<strong>` Entered name `</strong>`

Any idea why the html tags are not understood?

Many thanks

Comment: which mailer function you are using ?

Comment: You have to set the [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) to text/html

Answer (score 3):

You have to define your email as "HTML" :

```
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

 // Send...
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you chose `iso-8859-1` as the charset?

Comment: That's what the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3350) uses. So it must not be a bad choice.

Comment: Not specifically, indeed, just a copy and paste from one of my old code (I may have taken this from somewhere else before)... I think it is now better to use `UTF-8` instead, for example...

Comment: thanks a lot, that works :) how do you change to UTF-8, is it: $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n"; correct?

Comment: @LuizaRios Yes, it its.

Answer (score 0):

it gives an error because you are using special characters in your string. with the function htmlspecialchars you can convert them to html and then it will give no problem.
the htmlspecialchars will escape the < and > in your case

more info can be found in the php documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

Emails are by default sent as text emails.

To make the email client interpret the email body as HTML, you need to deliver the body in the right format, which is being indicated by the *Content-Type* field:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

You can insert this field in the *additional headers* parameter of PHP's [mail() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

See example #4 on the above link on how to send HTML email with PHP.